# Activating CGI for Apache2 ubuntu 14.04

Tags: apache, ubuntu, cgi

I am not able to set up cgi server however normal pages like /var/www/html/index.html are accessible. I am pretty new to setting up web servers and working with system setting, so it may be that I am missing something fundamental. 
I am following [apache's tutorial](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/howto/cgi.html) and [this](https://www.linux.com/blog/configuring-apache2-run-python-scripts) tutorial. And I think problem is because of LoadModule cgi_module modules/mod_cgi.so. But I am not sure.
I am writing what configuration changes I did.

In the file /etc/apache2/apache.conf I added following line:

```
Include /etc/apache2/httpd.conf
```

Then this is how /etc/apache2/httpd.conf looks:

```
<Directory /var/www/html/cgi>
Options ExecCGI
SetHandler cgi-script
</Directory>
<Directory /var/www/html>
Options +ExecCGI
AddHandler cgi-script .cgi .py
</Directory>
#LoadModule cgi_module modules/mod_cgi.so
```

Then I execute:

```
sudo a2enmod cgi
```

If I do this with last line of httpd.conf(LoadModule..) uncommented, I get following error:

```
apache2: Syntax error on line 146 of /etc/apache2/apache2.conf: Syntax error on line 12 of /etc/apache2/httpd.conf: Cannot load modules/mod_cgi.so into server: /etc/apache2/modules/mod_cgi.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
Your MPM seems to be threaded. Selecting cgid instead of cgi.
Module cgid already enabled
```

I looked at [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/54251/how-do-i-make-apache-run-a-cgi-instead-of-showing-the-text) answer. I did look in the mods-enabled directory and couldn't find cgi.load there, though cgid.load is present there.

With the LoadModule line in httpd.conf commented, I get following message on execution of sudo a2enmod cgi:

```
Your MPM seems to be threaded. Selecting cgid instead of cgi.
Module cgid already enabled
```

However in both cases when I try to open a test.py file from browser, I get

```
500 Internal Server Error
```

I don't think test.py has some problem. However it has only this one line:

```
print "Hello World"
```

Any help would be appreciated.